# Keras loss gets stuck at one point CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have 12k rgb images with 6 in one group of 100x100.

So I used Conv3d with shape (-1,100,100,3,6)

As an output, I have boolean (0 or 1)

So what I did is, I kept few CNN layers at first, flatten it for DNN layer and at lastly apply sigmoid activation function to get result from 0 to 1.

I have first 400 image with bool output 1 and other 1600 images with bool output 0.

So I wrote this code

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib.keras import models,layers,losses,optimizers


x=np.load('features.npy')

y=np.zeros(2000)
y[:400]=1

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv3D(32, (3,3,3), input_shape=(100,100,3,6),activation='linear',padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPool3D((2,2,2),padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(32, (3,3,3),activation='linear',padding='same'))
model.add(layers.MaxPool3D((2,2,2),padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(32, (3,3,3),activation='linear',padding='same'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='linear'))
model.add(layers.Dense(units=1,activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Nadam(),loss=losses.mean_absolute_percentage_error)
model.fit(x,y,epochs=10,shuffle=True,batch_size=20)

model.fit(x,y,epochs=100,shuffle=True,batch_size=20)

model.save_weights("model0.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")
```

but the problem is,
when applied sigmoid or any function which maps to limited space, the model always gives output as 0 or 1 and the loss always stays at 20

when i replace the last activation with linear, the model works great but as the linear function isn't suitable for binary output, it gives loss over a million.

[image: Output]

Comment: Please see here why it's not a good idea to post your code output as an image: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: mean_absolute_percentage_error has not so much sense as loss function in classification problems... try binary_crossentropy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binary output was acting weird for me, the model tried to either give all 0 or all 1.

so I replaced 1 to randint(90,100) and 0 to randint(0,10)

also changed the activation from sigmoid to relu

now every time model tries to get all 0's it would have a huge error and rectify itself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have used linear activations, use ReLU activations.

Also, in the penultimate Dense layer, you have used 10 units, consider using something in the range [128, 512].

One more thing to consider is that you have an unbalanced dataset. Try balancing your dataset by using equal number of samples.

Comment: Did you try balancing the data? And did you change the loss to binary cross-entropy?

Comment: Can you show me the training curve and validation curves? If you find the loss reducing slowly consider increasing the size of your layers.

Comment: Also, make the learning rate 1 or 0.1 to see if the loss is really changing. Use normal Adam, you can set learning rate easily there.